# Store array in cookie

Tags: php, arrays, serialization, cookies

I am converting the array into cookie by php serialize function

```
$PromoteProductArray = array("PromoteuserId"=>$PromoteuserId,
"PromoteProductId"=>$PromoteProductId,
"PromoteBrandId"=>$PromoteBrandId);

$Promotedcart[] = $PromoteProductArray;

setcookie("Promotedcart", serialize($Promotedcart), time()+604800,'/');
```

And when the cookie is created then i am using the unserialize php function.

```
print_r(unserialize($_COOKIE['Promotedcart']));
```

it does not work.

When I `print_R($_COOKIE)` then it show me the value.

Comment: Test data can be very helpful, can you post sample

Comment: [See this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032007/arrays-in-cookies-php) for a better answer.

Comment: Please do not use `unserialize` on user-submitted data. This is easily exploitable with object injection using PHP's __wakeup and __destruct methods. You can use `json_encode/json_decode` instead of `serialize/unserialize`. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Object_Injection

Answer (score 0):

Cookies separated by semicolon. Serialized strings with arrays contain them inside. Maybe this is a problem. You can use base64 to avoid all possible escape issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_encode`, `json_decode` functions to achieve this as an alternative.

```
$PromoteProductArray = array("PromoteuserId"=>$PromoteuserId,
"PromoteProductId"=>$PromoteProductId,
"PromoteBrandId"=>$PromoteBrandId);
$Promotedcart[] = $PromoteProductArray;
setcookie("Promotedcart", json_encode($Promotedcart), time()+604800,'/');
$result = json_decode($_COOKIE['Promotedcart'], true);
print_r($result);
```

Give it a try, this should work.