# putting array in cookie

Tags: php

I am trying to add 'recent viewed products' feature in my site. So i want to add the products recently watched in cookie. Setting cookie when user go to detail page of the product. So cookie setting code is in detail page.
What i am trying

```
setcookie('recentviews', $productid, time()+3600,'/')
```

What i need is

```
recentviews1 =>1
recentviews2 =>5
recentviews3 =>3
```

OR

```
recentviews (
[0] => 1,
[1] => 5,
[2] => 3
)
```

I tried alot of solutions, like setting cookie in loop, but how to know how many views are already set, so I can increment 'recentviews' and set new cookie.

Comment: Maybe you can json_encode the array before saving?

Comment: i tried serializing. but how to find how many vies i have already?

Comment: If you want to persist data just for server-side use sessions. Otherwise serialize, json would be the best suitable format, imho.

Comment: Yes either `json_encode()` or `serialize()`

Comment: no, not on server side. On client side. How to do with json?

Comment: @Kyra,  know serialize can help here. but i don't want to loose previous viewed products, so how i can do it in one cookie variable?

Comment: Is this feature for logged in clients? If so, you may want to store this in a database, as this sort `of data should be persistent regardless of whether the user switches browsers/computers.

Comment: In response to @Kyslik's response, if you absolutely need to store more than 4kb of data locally, you could look into localStorage (though this would be a JavaScript solution, which isn't tagged, but it's worth mentioning).

Comment: @hjpotter92, I don't want to loose the products already viewed

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go about something like this (imagining that the cookie content contains obly `safe` data):

```
# basic cookie structure:
$recent_views = array(
    # 'product_id' => 'value',
    32324 => 2,
    32455 => 23,
);


# to add a value in a request handler:
$recent_views = json_decode($_COOKIE['recentviews']);
$recent_views[ 32342 ] = 32;
setcookie('recentviews', json_encode( $recent_views ), $expi_time );
```

Error checking left out for brevity.

Json really has the advantage that you can easily decode the cookie in javascript in the browser and even make changes there.. (not what I would do, but still a possibility).

Cheers -

Answer (score 0):

you can follow below example

```
$info[7][5]=1;
$info[8][5]=1;
```

Serialize data:

```
setcookie('cookie', serialize($info), time()+3600);
```

Then unserialize data:

```
$data = unserialize($_COOKIE['cookie']);
```

After data, $info and $data will have the same content.

Comment: You copied it from here. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032007/arrays-in-cookies-php
Actually i want to keep track of old views as well.