# Use arrays on multiple php pages?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, web, submit

I am looking to use an array on 2 seperate pages of php. Not using Sessions a simple array, at the end of my page I use a Submit button to pass on to the 2nd page... how can I save the content of my array and print them on the 2nd page?

Comment: You could submit them as a serialized string, or as JSON. Please use the search on how to do this, since it has been answered multiple times on SO before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cookies to save list of array and fetch on the other page. [Arrays in cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032007/arrays-in-cookies-php). And if you don't need to use that data again you can delete the cookie

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 
encoded json(json_encode($array);) format inside the form
after submit you have to retrieve the data by json_decode($array,true);