# How to add new array item into existing array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to add new array item to an existing array.  I'm using `array_push` for this purpose but it is not working.

Array

```
Array ( [productID] => 51  )
```

Php Code

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['sendProductId'])){

    $inserted = $_COOKIE['productID'];
    $original = $_REQUEST['sendProductId'];

    if($inserted){
        $cookie_value   =   array_push( $inserted, $original ); 
    }else{
        $cookie_value = $_REQUEST['sendProductId'];
    }
    $cookie_name = 'productID';

    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30));

}
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

Actually I want to add products ids into a cookie. I have also used `array_splice` for this but it's also not working.

Please guide me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032007/arrays-in-cookies-php

Comment: @Semmix I think it is not duplicate because my question is totally different from above mention link

Comment: What is in `var_dump( $inserted);` ,`var_dump( $original);` ?

Comment: @ashkufaraz `string '51' (length=2)`  is result of this `var_dump( $inserted);`

Comment: and `var_dump( $original);`?

Comment: @ashkufaraz it does not giving any result because when i post data through ajax then its showing the value

Comment: `$original` has `Array ( [productID] => 51  )`?

Comment: ` $cookie_name = 'productID';`

Comment: Reading the [manual](http://php.net/array_push) would show you that you are using array_push() incorrectly.

Comment: @ashkufaraz where is your answer ?

Comment: You want set `productID=>51` and `productID=>52` in cookie ?

Comment: `$cookie_value` must equal to ??

Comment: `setcookie("TestCookie", $value);` `$value` is not array http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: @ashkufaraz I want set `productID=>51` and `productID=>52` in cookie

Comment: !!!! how can array with same key?

Comment: @ashkufaraz I want this `productID = array(51, 52)`

Comment: @AyazShah read my answer

Answer (score -1):

With `serialize(array())` set array to cookie and for read data use `$data = unserialize($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);`

so try this

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['sendProductId'])){

    $inserted = 51;//$_COOKIE['productID'];
    $original = 52;//$_REQUEST['sendProductId'];

    $cookie_name = 'productID';

    $cookie_value[0]   = $original;   
    if($inserted)
        $cookie_value[1]   = $inserted;   



    setcookie($cookie_name, serialize($cookie_value), time() + (86400 * 30));

}

$data = unserialize($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(52)
  [1]=>
  int(51)
}
```

Answer (score -3):

From the [documentation for array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php):

> `array_push` — Push one or more elements onto the end of array
>
> ```
> int array_push ( array &$array , mixed $value1 [, mixed $... ] )
> ```
>
> `array_push()` treats array as a stack, and pushes the passed
>   variables onto the end of array. The length of array increases by the
>   number of variables pushed. Has the same effect as:
>
> ```
> <?php
> $array[] = $var;
> ?>
> ```
>
> repeated for each passed value.