# Storing and retrieving an array in a PHP cookie

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I'm looking to store some data from some 'virtual' index cards. Each card has a front and a back, and the user can store multiple cards. Each side will have data on it.

```
I ----------------- I I CARD 1 FRONT I I------------------I
I --------------- I I CARD 1 BACK I I-----------------I
I ----------------- I I CARD 2 FRONT I I------------------I
I --------------- I I CARD 2 BACK I I-----------------I
```

OK, my diagrams got messed up a bit. But you get the message. :)

Imagine it from the diagrams above. I'd like to store each card's data (front and back) in a cookie, as an array (maybe), and then be able to pull each value back and insert it where applicable (on a different page).

At the same time, bear in mind that the user can make as many cards as they like. I can't use POST or GET functions. The array bit is debatable, if you can think of an easier way of storing this data in a cookie, let me know. Please note: don't suggest storing in a database, as it won't be convenient for the project. :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413161/store-array-in-cookie

Comment: Do you have a code example since the poster said his code was wrong? I can't quite work out where the semicolons would fit.

Comment: reg PS : Cant se why - your question has perfectly SO relevancy, but try ask on meta

Comment: show an example of the array

Comment: Well, I'd like to store the front value and the back value of each card, so for example:

CARD 1 FRONT
CARD 1 BACK
CARD 2 FRONT
CARD 2 BACK


...but the user can create an almost unlimited number of cards. :)

Comment: @MajidFouladpour, why did you insert off topic "Data" values?

Comment: @davidkonrad if you believe they are off topic you could remove them. I reasoned those are the actual sample data that a user stored on the cards, as using cards to store 'Card 1 Front', 'Card 1 Back' is not of much use.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour, I do not "believe" changing the entire fundamentals of the question is wrong, it **IS** wrong.  Reasons for edting a question is amongst other things ["To clarify the meaning of the post (**without changing that meaning**)"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) when you are changing the meaning of a question, you are also compromising the validity of all answers to that question.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use `json_encode` / `json_decode` to get / set arrays in cookies.

Test array

```
$cardArray=array(
    'CARD 1'=>array('FRONT I', 'BACK I'),
    'CARD 2'=>array('FRONT 2', 'BACK 2')
);
```

convert and write the cookie

```
$json = json_encode($cardArray);
setcookie('cards', $json);
```

the saved string looks like this

```
{"CARD 1":["FRONT I","BACK I"],"CARD 2":["FRONT 2","BACK 2"]}
```

get the cookie back

```
$cookie = $_COOKIE['cards'];
$cookie = stripslashes($cookie);
$savedCardArray = json_decode($cookie, true);
```

show the restored array

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($savedCardArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

outputs

```
Array
(
    [CARD 1] => Array
        (
            [0] => FRONT I
            [1] => BACK I
        )

    [CARD 2] => Array
        (
            [0] => FRONT 2
            [1] => BACK 2
        )

)
```

---

**Edit**
If you wonder about `stripslashes`, it is because the string saved actually is

```
{\"CARD 1\":[\"FRONT I\",\"BACK I\"],\"CARD 2\":[\"FRONT 2\",\"BACK 2\"]}
```

`setcookie` adds `\` before quoutes to escape them. If you not get rid of those, `json_decode` will fail.

---

**Edit II**

To add a new card to the cookie

1. load the array as above
2. `$savedCardArray['CARD XX']=array('FRONT XX', 'BACK XX');`
3. save the array as above, but now of course `$savedCardArray` and not `$cardArray`.

Comment: you are welcome! See edit for expl about stripslashes, forgot that.

Comment: Ah yes, that explains. One more question... How do I print/echo Card 1's front and back result? Would card 1 be the variable and then [0] print Card 1's front?

Comment: Yes! `echo $savedCardArray['CARD 1'][0].' '.$savedCardArray['CARD 1'][1];` wil output `FRONT I BACK I`

Comment: Will the count function work to count how many cards the user has made?

Comment: Yes. The result is a perfectly normal array - `count($savedCardArray)` and all other array functions is available.

Comment: Tried the code and it seems to work well. :)

I got a bit confused, though, when the user adds a new card. I understand I must pull back the cookie and add the new card - once I've returned the cookie, what is a logical way to add the new card data to the cookie?

Comment: see update. But this is really very basic :) BTW, Stackoverflow dont like multiple comments (you may have seen a message below)

Comment: The second parameter for json_encode should not be "true".  That would be the second parameter on json_decode.

Answer (score 3):

Serialize/Unserialize works as a simpler alternative to json_encode / json_decode

setcookie('cookiename', serialize(array), ...) to save to cookie.

array = unserialize($_COOKIE['cookienam']) to retrieve array.

Answer (score 2):

Play with something like this

```
<?php

$card_id = '123';
$value = 'im a black lady';

setcookie("card[$card_id][front]", $value);

// reload page to actually read the cookie

echo $_COOKIE['card'][$card_id]['front']; // im a black lady

?>
```

Comment: Thank you! :)

With regards to the Card ID, how would I extract that/store multiple card values? Sorry for a lack of understanding.

Comment: You need some kind of unique id to identify each card and their front/back values. How you define that depends on your structure. Perhaps set cards with user id and start with user card 1 and increase +1 for each card the user have. You can count($_COOKIE['user_id']) and step up card number from count result, or simply number them without user identification if thats sufficient.