# How to create cookie as array

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I referred to this to store array in cookie: [Storing and retrieving an array in a PHP cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068363/storing-and-retrieving-an-array-in-a-php-cookie)

However, I need each value stored as array.Below is my script:

```
/*store all values in array starts*/
$search_array=array(
    'category'=>array('cat', $catid),
    'subject'=>array('sub', $subject),
    'location'=>array('loc', $location),
    'rate'=>array('rate', $rate),
    'distance'=>array('dis', $distance)
);

/*store all values in array ends*/

/*cookies starts*/
$s_array= json_encode($search_array);
setcookie('search', $s_array);

/*cookies ends*/
```

In other page:

```
<?php
$cookie = $_COOKIE['search'];
$cookie = stripslashes($cookie);
$savedCardArray = json_decode($cookie, true);


var_dump($savedCardArray);
?>
```

The output is:

```
array (size=5)
  'category' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'cat' (length=3)
          1 => string '5' (length=1)
  'subject' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'sub' (length=3)
          1 => string 'Circuit Training' (length=16)
  'location' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'loc' (length=3)
          1 => string 'gombak' (length=6)
  'rate' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'rate' (length=4)
          1 => int 115
  'distance' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'dis' (length=3)
          1 => string '100' (length=3)
```

But what I want (1):

```
'category' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              0 => string 'cat' (length=3)
              array (size=4)
                 0 => string '5' (length=1)
                 1 => string '2' (length=1)
                 2 => string '4' (length=1)
                 3 => string '10' (length=1)
```

(2) to expire within 48 hours

Comment: How the other values in `cat` array are coming?

Comment: `$catid` should be an array containing the list of categories to be displayed under `cat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$search_array=array(
'category'=>array('cat', array($catid)),
...
);
```

in 48 hours

```
setcookie("search", $s_array, time()+(3600*48));
```