# Trouble setting array as value of cookie

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I need to set array as a value of cookie, and here I found reasonable solution: [Arrays in cookies PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032007/arrays-in-cookies-php). So here is what I have tried:

```
<?php        
   $array=array();
   foreach($columnList as $c_list) {
       foreach($c_list as $one_member) {
           echo '<button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><b>' . $one_member . '</b></button>';
           array_push($array,$one_member);
       }
   }
   setcookie('new_column',serialize($array), time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
?>
```

Note that I am looping through two-dimensional array and pushing each single value into array called `$array`. But when I do this :

```
print_r($_COOKIE['new_column']);
```

It displays only the first value, i.e. the first `$one_member`. And when I do this:

```
$data=unserialize($_COOKIE['new_column']);
print_r($data);
```

It basically displays nothing. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**:
I found what is the pre-issue of this issue in question, and here it is: I tried putting just this:

```
foreach($c_list as $one_member) {
    echo '<button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><b>' . $one_member . '</b></button>';
    $array=array();
    $array[]=$one_member;
 }
```

Without `array_push` and this returns just last `$one_member`. So I first need to fix this in order to put adequate array into cookie, but I don't even know why this occurs.

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068363/storing-and-retrieving-an-array-in-a-php-cookie

Comment: Is it `setcookie()` that does not seem to work or the array filling? You can check by printing `$array` and/or `serialize($array)` 's result.

Comment: It seems like `array_push` is not working, because when I `print_r($array)` it displays nothing.